# Finding a formula for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find the formula for linear transformation $\phi : \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\phi(\alpha_j)=\gamma_j $ for $j=1,2,3,4$
$\alpha_1 =[1,1,2,1],\alpha_2 =[1,2,1,1],\alpha_3 =[1,1,1,1],\alpha_4 =[1,1,1,0]$
$\gamma_1 =[0,1,1,1],\gamma_2 =[1,-1,1,1],\gamma_3 =[2,0,1,0],\gamma_4 =[2,2,3,2]$

my answer is the following:
$φ([x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 ])=[7x_1+2x_2+7x_3+4x_4,6x_1+x_2+7x_3+5x_4,5x_1+2x_2+6x_3+4x_4,3x_1+3x_3+2x_4 ]$ am i correct?

Comment: Nope.  Try $\varphi(\alpha_1)$ to see that you don't get $\gamma_1$.

Comment: are the $\alpha$'s columns or rows?

Comment: @abel For finding the formula for the transformation, it doesn't really matter.  It only matters if OP uses a matrix approach (like the one I suggested -- where I made them column matrices).

Comment: $\alpha$ are columns my another try for the formula is $[5x_1-x_2-2x_3,2x_1-x_2+x_3-2x_4,3x_1-2x_4,x_2+x_3-2x_4 ]$  this is possibly correct?

Comment: @kurkowski Yep.  That one's correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix which takes the standard basis vectors to the vectors $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$.  The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 &2 \end{bmatrix}$ takes the standard basis vectors to the vectors $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3, \gamma_4$.

You need a matrix which takes $\alpha_i$ to $\gamma_i$.

So how about you try composing the linear transformations $f$ which takes the vectors $\alpha_i$ to the standard basis vectors and $g$ which takes the standard basis vectors to $\gamma_i$ -- i.e. $g \circ f$?

HINT: I've already given you the matrix representation of one of those two transformations.  And the other can be found from the other matrix I gave you.

HINT $\#2$: What does function composition mean for matrices?